# Automatically change parameters to URL in iframe for every new connection

Tags: javascript, iframe, parameters

I am i-framing a Zoom meeting in a webpage using:

```
<iframe src= "https://zoom.us/wc/"meetingid"/join?prefer=1&un=dXNlcjE=&uel=dXNlcjFAdGVzdC5jb20=">
```

Is it possible to automatically assign a new value to **un** and **uel** for every new ip address that connects to the webpage or for every new access to the page?

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: Why would you want to do it by IP address?  That's tricky client-side, but also generally not the right approach.  There are entire countries that use one public IPv4 address.

Comment: Hi Brad, It doesn't need to be by ip address. It can be also every time the page is accessed. Not sure if that's possible though. The objective is that every different person that access the webpage is assigned a new random un & uel (username and email). If I just input a fixed URL as above, Zoom starts kicking people out of the meeting because they all have the same identification

Answer (score 0):

This is just a base64-encoded username and e-mail address.  You should probably generate something on your domain, rather than spoofing an address.  Depending on your server configuration, you can do something like:

```
zoom+35d17c5a-0bde-47db-a91b-200f963fd78f@example.com
```

If you use a UUID in this way, you guarantee that there won't be a collision.  I recommend using a proper UUID, and there are a handful of ways to generate one.  See also:  [Create GUID / UUID in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/105034/362536)

From there, you base64-encode for the url.  See also:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/247261/362536